# How to factor a nth degree binomial difference?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I know

$$
a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)
$$

and

$$
a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)
$$

but is there a formula to factor

$$
a^n-b^n=\space ?
$$

Thanks!

Comment: I've heard this called "nth degree" rather than "nth grade." Are you translating to English when you write your questions? (You're doing a good job; just asking out of curiosity.)

Comment: Degree is probably the correct term, I was searching for it with that name, but then my brain decided to spanglish my question! Nice catch!

Comment: This identity is called *difference of two nth powers* [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_two_squares).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may just expand
$$
(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})
$$ and observe what happens.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me why I couldn't find that anywhere? Am I using the wrong terminology?

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @undefined key words: **sum and difference of powers**, see this:https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Sum_and_difference_of_powers

Comment: Thanks again, you should add that source to your answer!

Answer (score 2):

$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b^1+a^{n-3}b^2+\dots+a^{n-k-1}b^k+\dots+b^{n-1})$

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me why I couldn't find that anywhere? Am I using the wrong terminology?

Comment: We don't necessarily name every identity that exists and I do not know a specific name for this identity.  I don't remember when I first learned this identity, but I first *proved* the identity during an introductory course in proof writing in the unit on induction, noting that $a^n-b^n=a(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1})+(a-b)b^{n-1}$